# Is it possible to scan documents in a flutter?

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to scan documents in a flutter, I have checked some of the QR code scanners are there [QR-code scanner library](https://github.com/rmtmckenzie/flutter_qr_mobile_vision/).
How can I scan the documents and save by using the flutter or do I need to write native code to utilize this.

Comment: You can use the camera or image_picker plugin. If you want a custom UI you can stll copy the native code of these plugins.

Comment: Which channel is best to call native code from IOS/Android `EventChannel` or `MethodChannel`

Answer (score 0):

**inside pubspec.yaml**

```
  barcode_scan: ^1.0.0
```

**inside main.dart**

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:barcode_scan/barcode_scan.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  home: QRApp(),
));

class QRApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  QRAppState createState() {
    return new QRAppState();
  }
}

class QRAppState extends State<QRApp> {
  String result = "Scan QR Code Or BAR Code And Get Result Here !";

  Future _scanQR() async {
    try {
      String qrResult = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
      setState(() {
        result = qrResult;
      });
    } on PlatformException catch (ex) {
      if (ex.code == BarcodeScanner.CameraAccessDenied) {
        setState(() {
          result = "Camera permission was denied";
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          result = "Unknown Error $ex";
        });
      }
    } on FormatException {
      setState(() {
        result = "You pressed the back button before scanning anything";
      });
    } catch (ex) {
      setState(() {
        result = "Unknown Error $ex";
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("QR Scanner"),
      ),
      body: Center(

        child:  Container(
          // padding: EdgeInsets.all(50),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30.0,left:30.0,right: 30.0),
          child:
          SelectableText(result+"\n\n\n"+"Select Above Result And copy",
            cursorColor: Colors.red,

            showCursor: true,
            style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            toolbarOptions: ToolbarOptions(
                copy: true,
                selectAll: true,
                cut: false,
                paste: false
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
        label: Text("Scan"),
        onPressed: _scanQR,
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -5):

We have recently released a Flutter plugin of our commercial scanner SDK for Android and iOS:
https://pub.dev/packages/scanbot_sdk

Comment: is it free ?fgfgf

Comment: it's not free, it's insanely expensive, $60k/yr lol

Comment: Thanks for your comments, guys. As I stated out, it's a **commercial** SDK.